# NuGet uses invalid feed when adding a new package

Tags: xamarin, nuget

I've been using both a public and a private feed for NuGet and I've added them in a `Nuget.Config` file in my project's root:

```xml
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="ligetFeed" value="http://graymini.local:9011/api/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />       
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Running `nuget restore` works fine, and restores packages from both nuget.org and my private feed, but while trying to add a new nuget from nuget.org, it fails because it uses the private feed instead of nuget.org. I've been trying to add it both from Visual Studio (Mac) and command line, via `nuget install <package>` but the same thing happens.

The output looks like this:

```
Feeds used:
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  http://privatefeed.local:9011/api/v3/index.json

Installing package 'Polly' to '/Users/user/Documents/MyProject'.
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration4-gz-semver2/polly/index.json
  GET http://privatefeed.local:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json
An error was encountered when fetching 'GET http://privatefeed.local:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json'. The request will now be retried.
mono-io-layer-error (-1)
  GET http://privatefeed.local:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json
An error was encountered when fetching 'GET http://privatefeed.local:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json'. The request will now be retried.
mono-io-layer-error (-1)
  GET http://privatefeed.local:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json
An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Polly' from source 'ligetFeed'.
  mono-io-layer-error (-1)
```

Notice it tries to use `GET http://privatefeed.local:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json` instead of `api.nuget.org`

Are there any extra steps needed? How does NuGet decide which feed to use?

N.B. I've managed to add the package just fine by removing the private feed entry from `Nuget.Config`, adding the package, then re-adding the feed and restoring, but this doesn't seem right on the long term.

Comment: Hi , do you publish it to nuget.org first ?

Comment: The nuget I'm trying to add exists on nuget.org (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly/) but the thing is "nuget install" uses the wrong feed. Instead of trying to fetch it from nuget.org, it fetches it from my private feed, even though both are specified in Nuget.Config as packageSources

Comment: Okey , if remove `ligetFeed` from `packageSources` , does `Polly` can be installed successfully ?

Comment: It does, as I've written in the last paragraph (N.B), but I can't really figure out how nuget chooses which feed to use for each package or if I could specify somehow which feed to be used for each package. Something like `package1 -> nuget.org`, `package2 -> privateFeed`, etc. Occasionally I've encountered errors during restore as well or while trying to update packages due to the same probem, nuget using the wrong feed, but they seem to go away after `dotnet restore`. Not the same case when adding a new package though, it will continue to fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a problem with mono and mDNS (.local). I've been using Mac OS for the Nuget Feed with LiGet and as you may know, you can access any other Mac on the network with either the IP or `name.local`, as I did with `graymini.local`

After replacing the feed in `NuGet.Config` from

```xml
<add key="ligetFeed" value="http://graymini.local:9011/api/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
```

to

```xml
<add key="ligetFeed" value="http://22.33.444.555:9011/api/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
```

Everything seems to work fine. Trying to obtain the new package from the private feed will return `NotFound` instead of erroring with `mono-io-layer-error` and it will continue just fine fetching it from nuget.org instead.

```
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration4-gz-semver2/polly/index.json
  GET http://22.33.444.555:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json
  NOTFOUND http://22.33.444.555:9011/api/v3/registration/polly/index.json 
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration4-gz-semver2/polly/index.json
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately** , there is no way to set the an *OPTIONAL* priority for feeds to solve that problem .I hope can do that as follow :

```
<packageSources>
    <!-- Internal package source comes before NuGet.org proxy -->   
    <add key="my_private_feed" value="http://internal-server:8081/repository/private_feed1/" priority="1" />
    <add key="cache_nugetorg" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" priority="2" />
</packageSources>
```

However , it can not support . From [this issue link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3676) , I know that :

> This is by design, sources are unordered and they are searched by order of the quickest response rather than by order of how they show up in file.

By the way , there is an unperfect way to set `nuget.org` disable by using `activePackageSource` and `disabledPackageSources` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Chuck Norris Feed" value="https://www.myget.org/F/chucknorris" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="Chuck Norris Feed" value="https://www.myget.org/F/chucknorris" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

However , this way also can't realize it. I also find [this issue link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5611) , Priority methods have been proposed as suggestions .

**Finally** , I will look forward to such a method in the future.